# element forces an other element to be smaller in html

Tags: html, css

## Background info

I am building a site which displays pictures to its users. This site uses a table for the 'posts'.

## The problem

When I add the picture (or a div) to the table, it automatically resizes the column next to it. You can look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hsNpj/ The red DIV forces the column to the left of it to be smaller than its defined width. Weird. I thought that width means width and not 'width something like'.

Here is the code to the CSS which should define the widht to 100px:

```
td.postopt
{
    background:#f6f6f6;
    width:100px;
    border-right:1px solid #666;
    height:100%;
}
```

Why does HTML&CSS do this? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display:block;`. This will force `td` to take the width specified.

Comment: you have set too much padding for the content on the right, you need to work on that one too.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Do note that I did not make the td display as a block, rather the div inside of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an overflow rule (`overflow: scroll;`) for example.  This will tell the browser what to do when there is more content in an element than the element can contain.

Also, remember that tables and table elements don't quite behave the same as standard layout elements.